# Accessing data using Dynamic IP from API which allows only static IP

Tags: python, api, heroku, ip, pythonanywhere

I made a script which accesses some data from an API. The problem is that to access the API I have to visit their website and enter my IP in allowed IPs list to get the authorization key for that specific IP. There no such option to allow all IPs. Now my script is running on PythonAnywhere which is a free cloud service and doesn't provide static IP. So any idea how I can get a static IP? or maybe any other free cloud service which provides static IP. I tried Heroku too with that QuotaGuard extension but it asks for credit card details first and I don't have one.
Is there any service out there which can be accessed from any IP address and then use a private IP to get content and deliver that content to me?

Answer (score 0):

If the provider doesn't support giving you a static IP, you use a proxy server.

On Heroku there we have the [fixie](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie) or [quotaguard](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/quotaguardshield) addons that could help here.

Comment: They require credit card details for the same and I don't have one. Any other way?

Comment: any other proxy provider, there are plenty, but I don't know which work without credit card